# Azure deployment continually recycling since upgrading the June 2012 SDK 1.7

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a deployment that was working successfully previously. Since then I have upgraded to the June 2012 SDK and when I deploy it is continually recycling. If I remote desktop into the instance i can open the application manually and it runs (no yellow screen of death), so there must be something about the deployment.

In the event viewer I see the error:

Faulting application WaHostBootstrapper.exe, version 6.0.6002.18488, time stamp 0x4fcaabe9, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6002.18520, time stamp 0x4e811810, exception code 0xc0000008, fault offset 0x00000000000b6ff8, process id 0x%9, application start time 0x%10.

But this isn't particularly useful. I have totally recreated the Cloud project with SDK 1.7. It is a ASP.NET MVC 4 RC application.

What can I do to see the exact reason for this error?

Comment: Are you running on a Server 2008 instance or 2008 R2 instance?  We had issues with our MVC app and server 08 -> changes to 08 R2 and never had another problem.  Neither config gave us issue on the local emulator during this time.

Comment: It is 2008 SP2 currently. I will try on R2 and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yeah let me know.  Since I do not know the specifics of why/how this worked for us, I didn't want to post as an answer.

Comment: I changed to R2 but no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your statement "I have totally recreated the Cloud project with SDK 1.7. It is a **ASP.NET MVC 4 RC** application.", I am not sure if 1) you are really using MVC4.0 RC bits or 2) you are using MVC 4.5 BETA bits. MVC 4.0 is already released and installing June 2012 SDK actually installs ASP.NET MVC 4.0 based Cloud Template and binaries, so you must be using release bits of MVC 4.0 with Windows Azure Cloud Project. If you are using RC bits, this could be your first problem.

I have seen the exact same error in past and described the reason and a potential fix for such problem in my blog: [Windows Azure Web Role Error: "Faulting application WaHostBootstrapper.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/06/29/windows-azure-web-role-error-quot-faulting-application-wahostbootstrapper-exe-quot.aspx)

I believe your package does not have necessary DLL so please check which DLL are missing in your deployment and redeploy your application to solve this problem.

Also if you want to run your application with Windows Server 2008 R2 as default, you can modify osFamily=2 (1:Windows Server 2008 SP2, 2:Windows Server 2008 R2) setting in your [ServiceConfiguration.cscfg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710) as below to configure at deployment:

```
<ServiceConfiguration 
    serviceName="<service-name>" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" 
    osFamily="2" 
    osVersion="*" 
    schemaVersion="2012-05.1.7">
```

Comment: Yes, I am using MVC 4.0 that comes with the the June 2012 SDK and the cloud templates and binaries. I didn't realise that was a final and not RC version though.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, the RC part made me little concern. IF you have released bits then try to look your package (or E:\approot\bin folder on Azure VM) to match with all the DLL in your project for missing DLL.

Comment: One problem is that I am not sure of the missing DLL. How can I work that out as the application works if I am logged on and catch it between recycles.

Comment: Not a different answer, but perhaps helpful - Missing DLLs may be caused by a web role project that references a worker role project, or vice versa.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679174/azure-package-not-including-linked-project-dll-even-with-copy-local-set

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading to v1.7, but upon looking at the Windows Azure logs in the Azure VM I noticed the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred. Type: System.ArgumentException Process ID: 2340
Process Name: DiagnosticsAgent
Thread ID: 1
AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role Backend_IN_0
Exception: Endpoint http://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/ is not a secure connection.
```

So I changed the Diagnostics connection string to use `https` instead of `http` and voilá, that solved my problem.

Hope that works for you, I've been pulling my hair off for two days.